# Are there any workarounds for pandas casting INT to Float when NaN is present?

Tags: python, pandas, int

Trying to get my column to be formatted as INT as the 1.0 2.0 3.0 is causing issues with how I am using the data.  The first thing I tried was `df['Severity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Severity'], errors='coerce')`.  While this looked like it worked initially, it reverted back to appearing as float when I wrote to csv.  Next I tried using `df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].astype(int)` followed by another failed attempt using `df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].astype(int, errors='coerce')` because it seemed a logical solution to me.

I did some digging into pandas' docs and found this regarding how pandas handles NAs:

```
Typeclass   Promotion dtype for storing NAs
floating    no change
object  no change
integer cast to float64
boolean cast to object
```

What I find strange though, is that when I run df.info(), I get `Severity                        452646 non-null object`

Sample Data:

```
Age,Severity
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,NaN
5,4
6,4
7,5
8,7
9,6
10,5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have found this to be a limitation of pandas.

Comment: Well, that is a rather large shame and makes me sad :(

Comment: You have to either drop them or replace them with an integer value, `NaN` cannot be represented by integer, this has nothing to do with pandas and more to do with numpy and in general terms number representation limitations in computer languages. It's the same problem for C++ as it is for python and probably lots of other languages. You get `object` as the `dtype` because the type is mixed here see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @EdChum, Thanks!  Setting NaN to 0 works fine with my application.

Comment: Specifically in that wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Integer_NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you how to handle missing values there is no correct way as it's up to you. You can either drop them using `dropna` or replace/fill them using `replace/fillna`, note that there is no way to represent `NaN` using integers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Integer_NaN.

The reason you get `object` as the `dtype` is because you now have a mixture of integers and floats. Depending on the operation then the entire Series maybe upcast to `float` but in your case you have mixed dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

As of pandas 0.24 (January 2019), it is possible to do what you want by using the [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na), using an [`arrays.IntegerArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html#pandas.arrays.IntegerArray) to represent the data:

```
In [83]: df.Severity
Out[83]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
4    4.0
5    4.0
6    5.0
7    7.0
8    6.0
9    5.0
Name: Severity, dtype: float64

In [84]: df.Severity.astype('Int64')
Out[84]:
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
4      4
5      4
6      5
7      7
8      6
9      5
Name: Severity, dtype: Int64
```